# sed -- Remove non-standard characters

Tags: html, css, bash, sed, utf-8

Hello all I have been trying to research and come up with a clean way of doing this ..

I have a .sql file that's full of bad characters from people copying and pasting from non standardized files etc etc and I have been tasked with removing the characters that have appeared as a result.

An example would be --

```
â€œ some text here â€ more text
```

The database is extensive and I am not sure about the variety of non-standard utf-8 characters there are .... So is there a `sed` parameter that can remove all non-standard characters (since I don't know exactly WHAT characters there are)?

These blocks are standard HTML and CSS blocks in the DB, so there's a limited number of allowable characters anyway, so should I go that route with a massive regex IE

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9`~!@#$%^&*()_\-+={[}\] \\|:;"'<,>.?\/]
```

Being that this is stored `HTML` and `CSS` I don't see the need to preserve tabs and spaces (or they would have kept it in files).

The above `regex` in a `sed` statement seems wonky and a bit hack-ish.

Is there a cleaner way to search these characters out and remove them?

I have tried what a lot of SOs answers suggest, but most answers only contain a single, or few characters .. I want to rid anything that isn't "standard" utf-8

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick:

```
iconv -f ORIGINAL_ENCORDING (utf-8) -t utf-8 -c yourfile.sql
```

Comment: question, is there a way to move through a directory (multiple .sql files)?

Comment: This only works if I know what the original encoding is .. Which I do not .. I could be multiple versions of encoding for that matter --  I am new to this project, so up until now, there was zero control on input into the database ..

Comment: Is there a reason why each file would be encoded differently?

Comment: maybe try `enca` in your shell

Comment: NO ...  Each file will **contain** characters from BOTH `utf-8` AND other encoding .. There were multiple MySQL clients used (with different encoding) and the MySQL server was `utf-8`  ..  So you can see now that a single field could have `LATIN1` characters as well as `WINDOWS-1251` AND `utf-8`